# All system logs lack end of message newlines

Tags: centos6, rsyslog

We have a curious issue where all logs in `/var/log/` lack a trailing new-lines at the end of their messages, and instead contain an `n`, but the entire file is one 'line':

```
Jun  4 10:18:54 host sshd[12468]: Accepted publickey for username from xx.xx.xx.xxx port xxxx ssh2nJun  4 10:18:54 host sshd[12468]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user username by (uid=0)nJun  4 10:19:25 host sudo: username : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/username ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bashn
```

Super bizarre.  I looked everywhere, and the only complaints about a "lack of newlines" I can find on the internet refer to the messages themselves not being multi-line (lack on newlines in the message body).  However I can not find anything on a lack of trailing newlines, or on modifying/confirming the format of the messages.

Answer (score 1):

**Cause:** One of our sysadmins had modified the RSyslog template, and omitted the `\` before the `n` at the end of the template.

The RSyslog configuration file, located at `/etc/rsyslog.conf` allows to specify templates for the Messages:

```
# Use default timestamp format
#$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat
$template CustomFormat,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%\n"
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate CustomFormat
```

Well, the admin had omitted the `\` for the newline, resulting in:

```
$template CustomFormat,"%timegenerated% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg:::drop-last-lf%n"
```

No dice.

To summarize, if you have odd format issues in any logs handled by RSyslog, check the Template configurations for RSyslog, starting in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`